# Convert utf-16 to utf-8 using python

Tags: python, utf-8, utf-16

I am trying to convert a huge csv file from utf-16 to utf-8 format using python and below is the code:

```
with open(r'D:\_apps\aaa\output\srcfile, 'rb') as source_file:
            with open(r'D:\_apps\aaa\output\destfile, 'w+b') as dest_file:
                contents = source_file.read()
                dest_file.write(contents.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8'))
```

But this code uses lots of memory and fails with Memoryerror. Please help me with an alternate method.

Comment: Split the file? Perhaps it would help to specify the encoding when opening the files? Then, if possible, you could perhaps stream directly from one file to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an option is to convert the file line by line:

```
with open(r'D:\_apps\aaa\output\srcfile', 'rb') as source_file, \
        open(r'D:\_apps\aaa\output\destfile', 'w+b') as dest_file:
    for line in source_file:
        dest_file.write(line.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8'))
```

---

or you could open the files with your desired encoding:

```
with open(r'D:\_apps\aaa\output\srcfile', 'r', encoding='utf-16') as source_file, \
        open(r'D:\_apps\aaa\output\destfile', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as dest_file:
    for line in source_file:
        dest_file.write(line)
```

Comment: glad to hear! happy pythoning!

Comment: In the second solution, you have to use modes without "b", ie. `'r'` and `'w+'` as the second args to `open()`.

Comment: @lenz Yes, you are right. I did the same.