# Fastest way to convert CSV files from UTF-16 tabs, to UTF-8-SIG commas

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, tableau-desktop

I have two 30 gb CSV files, each contains tens of millions of records.

[image]

They are using commas as delimiter, and saved as UTF-16 (thanks Tableau :-( )

I wish to convert these files to utf-8-sig with commas instead of tabs.

I tried the following code (some variables are declared earlier):

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv(p, encoding=encoding, dtype=str, low_memory=False, error_bad_lines=True, sep=' ')
csv_df.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, os.path.basename(p)), encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

And I have also tried:
[Convert utf-16 to utf-8 using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508111/convert-utf-16-to-utf-8-using-python)

Both work slowly, and practically never finish.

Is there a better way to make the conversion? Maybe Python is not the best tool for this?

Ideally, I would love the data to be stored in a database, but I'm afraid this is no a plausible option at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: When you want to speed up things, you need to do some profiling first – finding the bottleneck is key, otherwise you waste time optimising the wrong parts. For example, if the disk is slow, optimising the code won't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted a 35GB file in two minutes, Note that you can optimize performances by changing the constants in the top lines.

```
BUFFER_SIZE_READ = 1000000  # depends on available memory in bytes
MAX_LINE_WRITE = 1000  # number of lines to write at once

source_file_name = 'source_fle_name'
dest_file_name = 'destination_file_name'
source_encoding = 'file_source_encoding'  # 'utf_16'
destination_encoding = 'file_destination_encoding'  # 'utf_8'
BOM = True  # True for utf_8_sig

lines_count = 0


def read_huge_file(file_name, encoding='utf_8', buffer_size=1000):
    def read_buffer(file_obj, size=1000):
        while True:
            data = file_obj.read(size)
            if data:
                yield data
            else:
                break

    source_file = open(file_name, encoding=encoding)
    buffer_in = ''
    for buffer in read_buffer(source_file, size=buffer_size):
        buffer_in += buffer
        lines = buffer_in.splitlines()
        buffer_in = lines.pop()
        if len(lines):
            yield lines
        else:
            break


def process_data(data):
    def write_lines(lines_to_write):
        with open(dest_file_name, 'a', encoding=destination_encoding) as dest_file:
            if BOM and dest_file.tell() == 0:
                dest_file.write(u'\ufeff')
            dest_file.write(lines_to_write)
        return ''

    global lines_count
    lines = ''
    for line in data:
        lines_count += 1
        lines += (line + '\n')
        if not lines_count % MAX_LINE_WRITE:
            lines = write_lines(lines)
    if len(lines):
        with open(dest_file_name, 'a', encoding=destination_encoding) as dest_file:
            write_lines(lines)


for buffer_data in read_huge_file(source_file_name, encoding=source_encoding, buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE_READ):
    process_data(buffer_data)
```

Comment: omfg, this is insane!!!! The code was completed in less than 30 seconds!!!!

One tiny ask - The output delimiter is still Tab. How can I change it to a comma?

Comment: If your data is NOT contained tabs as part of values, then I guess you can use the string replace method to replace all '\t' with ',' on 'buffer' data, right before (or even within) chaining it to 'buffer_in' (inside the read_huge_file function). If you do have tabs as part of your data, then it is going to be a bit more challenging. Both going to seriously slow down the conversion.

Comment: Thanks Ze'ev. I will leave the tabs of that concern. Is there a way to export the data to a df rather than a file? I get the neuance of a simple bulk read/write, but asking just in case. Thanks!

Comment: I've never tried to load such a big file into a Dataframe. I'm not sure about the memory consumption and the loading time-consuming. maybe if you use the process_data function to split the huge file into smaller files then it will be more practical.